# Kubernetes - exposing cluster to external access with cloudflare proxy

Tags: nginx, networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I currently have the following setup:

- Cloudflare https proxied dns which routes ALL traffic to my server (end-to-end [client->proxy and proxy->server] encryption with CloudFlare Origin CA)
- Nginx reverse-proxy that acts as an SSL termination for all traffic to my server (origin signed cert I believe)
- Nginx proxies anything that goes to kube.my-domain.com to my kubeapi server as follows: `proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:6443`
- kubeapi running on my server

Currently I can connect to my cluster just fine by specifying in my kubeconfig:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443  <-----------------------------
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: test-namespace
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
```

But if I change the server in kubeconfig to point to my domain: `server: https://kube.my-domain.com` I get the following error:

```
user@master:~$ kubectl get deployments
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Now I assume this is because my traffic has to go through cloudflare's proxy and has different certs along the way. So I try appending --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true and get teh following response:

```
user@master:~$ kubectl get deployments --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "deployments"
```

So I look this up and find out a lot of the time it's due to RBAC (even though I should be authenticating as kubernetes-admin, which worked when I connected locally...)

```
I0317 00:41:09.281404   31989 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /home/user/.kube/config
I0317 00:41:09.281813   31989 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.17.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/06ad960" 'https://kube.my-domain.com/api?timeout=32s'
I0317 00:41:09.493885   31989 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://kube.my-domain.com/api?timeout=32s 403 Forbidden in 212 milliseconds
I0317 00:41:09.493921   31989 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0317 00:41:09.493970   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Set-Cookie: REDACTED; expires=Thu, 16-Apr-20 04:41:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.my-domain.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
I0317 00:41:09.493991   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Expect-Ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="REDACTED"
I0317 00:41:09.494002   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Server: cloudflare
I0317 00:41:09.494027   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Cf-Ray: REDACTED
I0317 00:41:09.494065   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2020 04:41:09 GMT
I0317 00:41:09.494070   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I0317 00:41:09.494091   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Cf-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
I0317 00:41:09.494112   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I0317 00:41:09.498893   31989 request.go:1017] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/api\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{},"code":403}
I0317 00:41:09.503266   31989 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.17.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/06ad960" 'https://kube.my-domain.com/apis?timeout=32s'
I0317 00:41:09.640948   31989 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://kube.my-domain.com/apis?timeout=32s 403 Forbidden in 137 milliseconds
I0317 00:41:09.640992   31989 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0317 00:41:09.641000   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2020 04:41:09 GMT
I0317 00:41:09.641006   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I0317 00:41:09.641011   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Cf-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
I0317 00:41:09.641016   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Expect-Ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="REDACTED"
I0317 00:41:09.641021   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Set-Cookie: REDACTED; expires=Thu, 16-Apr-20 04:41:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.my-domain.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
I0317 00:41:09.641027   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I0317 00:41:09.641031   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Server: cloudflare
I0317 00:41:09.641056   31989 round_trippers.go:452]     Cf-Ray: REDACTED
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, what is the best way to expose my cluster and keep it secure?

I feel like it has to do with the SSL termination at NGINX removing what's necessary for the api-server to recognize me.

Thanks.

UPDATE: It seems like either cloudflare proxy pr NGINX is stripping away the authentication certificate and key and is therefore causing the user of the request to become anonymous. Still looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown
>   authority

Above error indicates that the server certificate presented by https://kube.my-domain.com endpoint is not signed by certificate authority that you have in the kubeconfig file `certificate-authority-data` section. In kubeconfig you need to configure correct certificate authority(CA).

Comment: I'll try that but wouldn't the --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true skip the need for that?

thanks for the quick response, I'll try this in the meantime and report back

Comment: Do I need to change the CA config on the server as well? I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: How did you setup your cluster? I would say use same ca to generate all certs

Comment: I used kubeadm init from the following guide:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: In my kubeconfig I'm putting the following root CA's: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507#h_30cc332c-8f6e-42d8-9c59-6c1f06650639

Is this correct? I also tried the signed certificate that is beign used by nginx to terminate ssl but no luck

Comment: From nginx if you want to forward to Kubernetes API Server over https then you need to have Kubernetes API Server CA cert in nginx as well I believe

Comment: I think you're right, I'm currently looking at trying it with: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/ I'll see if this works

Comment: Do you think I have to change the cert that's in my kubeconfig to my cloudflare cert? and then only use the kubernetes cert from nginx onwards?

Comment: No its not needed actually...origin CA is used only between cloudflare and nginx and will not be trusted by any browser and client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209751/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-user2896438).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry I was neck deep in some docs and didnt notice you post this. I'm in chat now

Comment: Upvoting for the extensive amount of time you spent helping me debug this. If I figure out a solution I'll mark yours correct and write up a proper solution that you can post :) Thanks again

Comment: Hey, not sure if you're still around. I made some SIGNIFICANT progress on this problem. I ended up making my own RBAC admin account and storing its own auth token (not auth certificate) in the kubeconfig which allowed me to properly authenticate if I run `kubectl get nodes --insecure-skip-tls-verify`. I can finally authenticate as a proper user and see resources. Now the only final problem is to somehow set the SSL depth so that it's checking SSL against second SSL termination, not the first. Is there a way to do this? I feel like it has something to do with SSL chains

Comment: The key was authenticating with tokens and not with certificates

Comment: Thanks, I just need to figure out how to set SSL depth to verify deeper than the first termination, so that I dont have to --skip-verify. Do you have any ideas? Also I'm going to write up a solution and place it here, you can make it your answer and I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: can you verify what is the ca cert that has signed the server cert presented by the API Server endpoint...the endpoint that you specify in kubeconfig...the ca cert in kubeconfig needs to be the same cert

Comment: I think we tried this already but ill try again, I have the CA .pem here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin/origin-ca/

Will kubeconfig take PEM if I remove all newlines? Or do I have to convert it to different format somehow? I cnt find anything in docs about this.

thanks

Comment: And can you specify multiple CA's? Because theres two CAs in the path from client to server